# demonstrate that $C_A (B \cap C) = C_A (B) \cup C_A (C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$C_A (B \cup C) = C_A (B) \cap C_A (C)$$

Attempt: [image]

I'm right?

Comment: What is $C_A(B)$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy complementary of B in relation to A. I don't know how to do the notation in latex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B = \{x\in A \mid p(x)\}$ and $C = \{x\in A \mid q(x)\}$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
C_{A}(B\cap C) & = \{x\in A \mid \neg(p(x)\wedge q(x))\}\\\\
& = \{x\in A \mid \neg p(x)\vee\neg q(x)\}\\\\
& = \{x\in A \mid \neg p(x)\}\cup\{x\in A \mid \neg q(x)\}\\\\
& = C_{A}(B)\cup C_{A}(C)
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The proof could be reworded as a very neat one as follows.

*Proof.* The conclusion follows from the following equations:

\begin{align*}
x\in C_A(B\cup C)&\iff x\in A\text{ and }x\notin(B\cup C)\\
&\iff x\in A\text{ and not }x\in(B\cup C)\\
&\iff x\in A\text{ and not }(x\in B\text{ or }x\in C)\\
&\iff x\in A\text{ and }((\text{not }x\in B)\text{ and (not }x\in C))\\
&\iff x\in A\text{ and }(x\notin B\text{ and }x\notin C)\\
&\iff (x\in A\text{ and }x\notin B)\text{ and }(x\in A\text{ and }x\notin C)\\
&\iff x\in C_A(B)\text{ and }x\in C_A(C)\\
&\iff x\in C_A(B)\cap C_A(C).
\end{align*}

---

By the way, we usually use $A-B$ or $A\backslash B$ to denote the complement of $B$ in (relation to) $A$, and so your conclusion could be reworded as $A-(B\cup C)=(A-B)\cap(A-C)$.